# Google Translate API : Multiple input texts - Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I am struggling to find a way to input multiple texts in Google Translate API.
My setup includes the following things.

- Using `urllib.request.build_opener` (Python3)
- Google Translate API [https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate)
- I know that we can pass multiple parameters (Multiple "q"), but I don't know how to do it with Python.[image]
- I referred Google Translate documents. I found this.[image]

**My Question :**
How to add multiple texts to the input. ? Because the following code is not making any sense to me.

```
data = {'q':'cat', 'q':'dog','source':source,'target':target,'format':'html'}
```

This is my code.

```
data = {'q':'This is Text1', 'q':'This is Text2', 'q':'This is Text3', source':source,'target':target,'format':'html'}
_req = urllib.request.Request("https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key="+API_KEY)
_req.add_header('Content-length', len(data))
_req.data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode("utf-8")
response = Connector._get(_req,_session)
```

`Connector._get()` is in some other file and it internally calls `urllib.request.build_opener` with data.

Thanks!

Comment: @Nadan Bhat Can you also show some of of python code you use to build your request to google api ?

Comment: @Hugo I have updated the question.

Comment: what solution did you found finally, can you share?

Comment: @T.Todua `{'q':strings, 'source':source,'target':target,'format':'html'}` where `strings` is a list. `['my text', 'second text']`

Comment: @NandanBhat ok thnx,. you could have posted that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post multiple parameters (with the same name) in Python for an HTTP request, you can use a list for the values. They'll be added to the URL like `q=dog&q=cat`.

Example:

```
headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
params = {'q': ['cat', 'dog'],'source':source,'target':target,'format':'html'}
response = requests.post(
            "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=",
            headers=headers,
            params=params
        )
```

Specifically, `params = {'q': ['cat', 'dog']}` is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have tested by myself, but it seems that you should build the data string to give as data argument to your python urllib.request method. So something like data = "{\n \'q\':{}\n \'q\':{} {} etc.".format(qstr,qstr, etc...)

After that you could want to make it more painfull to have several qs.
You could make a loop and building your string with += operations.

Comment: Yeah ! But what I was thinking, As I have mentioned in the question, in Google Translate API they have showed the implementation. And also it works when I try from REST client (PostMan). I think that shouldn't be that complicated. There must be some easy workaround.

Comment: Ok I have tried just to make q a list of str in data dictionnary and printing _req.data is not ugly, hahaha. Maybe try it
data = { 'q': [str1,str2,str3] , etc. }